# Remote debugging, creating a server

Tags: windbg, remote-debugging

I'm following some WinDbg instructions from the [CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx).

To start a server, I can get this to work from the command line fine:

```
WinDbg –server npipe:pipe=pipename
```

(note: multiple clients can connect).

Where do I enter this from the windbg UI? I tried the command browser window, but that didn't seem to do anything:

```
.server npipe:pipe=pipename
```

(note: single client can connect)

This question is related to creating the server from WinDbg UI, not connecting from the client.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are referring to usermode debugging here, so I will respond with that in mind.

From windbg attached to your program that you want to remote:

If you want to use symbols that are cached on the target, then run:
from the Command Window's prompt type .server npipe:pipe=YourPipeName

If you have another machine with with a larger symbol cache, then on the target run:
dbgsrv -t tcp:port=4000

This sets up a thin debug client (a.k.a. remote stub)
Then on the machine running the debugger, open Windbg > File > Connect to remote stub
tcp:server= machine_running_dbgsrv ,port=4000

Now hit F6 and attach to the process you want to debug.

Note: the versions of windbg have to be the same on the machine running dbgsrv and the one running windbg. If they don't match, when you get to part where you hit F6, you end up with no processes in the process list.

- Jason

Answer (score 0):

File -> Connect to remote session. Or just use CTRL-R.

Comment: I can connect from the client with no problem. I'm just curious to how to start the server from the UI instead of the command line. I tried what you suggested from the server UI, but it wasn't able to create server pipe. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I'll edit my original post.